# Android : Define my App to Firefox browser as download manager

Tags: android, firefox, download

I'm programming a download manager application in android .
I create this Intent-Filter in Manifest :

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="ftp" />
            <data android:host="*" />
```

Google Chrome define my app as a download manager successfully but Mozila Firefox not show my App in Intent dialog by clicking each link.

Please help me to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution .
Put here for use anyone :
Add this Lines in you manifest :

```
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```